# E/Push Sample - UALib: Required permission com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE is unknown to PackageManager

Tags: android, urbanairship.com

Can Some one please help me on this, what is the problem i'm facing here, why i'm getting this kind of error .

UALib: Required permission com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE is unknown to PackageManager.

I'm using android urbanirship SDK for push notification, running on emulator . it is not giving PUSH APID :

```
the manifest file looks like this

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>enter code here
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0" package="com.younix.push.sample">

    <!-- minSdkVersion sets runtime compatibility ("will run on API level 4") -->
    <!-- targetSdkVersion should be set to the latest version tested, to disable compatibility modes 
            ("was tested with API level 9 features") -->
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" 
        android:targetSdkVersion="9"/>

    <!-- REQUIRED PERMISSIONS (for Urban Airship GCM) -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" /><!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" /> <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" /><!-- This app has permission to register with GCM and receive message -->

    <!-- MODIFICATION REQUIRED - Replace "com.urbanairship.push.sample" with your package name -->
    <permission android:name="com.younix.push.sample.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.younix.push.sample.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <!-- The two elements above ensure that only this application can receive the messages and registration result -->

    <!--  END Urban Airship Required Permissions -->

    <!-- OPTIONAL Urban Airship Settings -->
    <!-- REQUIRED FOR LOCATION -->
    <!-- Use ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION if GPS access is not necessary -->
    <!-- uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!--  OPTIONAL - This permission is only necessary if your app has multiple processes -->
    <!--  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" /> -->

    <!-- END OPTIONAL Urban Airship Settings -->

    <application android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
        android:name="com.younix.push.sample.MyApplication" 
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:allowClearUserData="true" 
        android:enabled="true">

        <activity android:name="com.younix.push.sample.MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.younix.push.sample.PushPreferencesActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.younix.push.sample.LocationActivity" />

        <!-- REQUIRED for Urban Airship GCM-->
        <receiver android:name="com.urbanairship.CoreReceiver" />

        <receiver android:name="com.urbanairship.push.GCMPushReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">        
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
              <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

              <!-- MODIFICATION REQUIRED - Use your package name as the category -->
              <category android:name="com.younix.push.sample" />
          </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.urbanairship.push.PushService" android:label="Push Notification Service"/>
        <service android:name="com.urbanairship.push.PushWorkerService" android:label="Push Notification Worker Service"/>
        <service android:name="com.urbanairship.analytics.EventService" android:label="Event Service"/>

        <!-- This is required for persisting preferences related to push and location -->
        <provider android:name="com.urbanairship.UrbanAirshipProvider"
            android:authorities="com.younix.push.sample.urbanairship.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:multiprocess="true" />
        <!-- END OF REQUIRED ITEMS -->


        <!-- OPTIONAL (for segments support) -->
        <service android:name="com.urbanairship.location.LocationService" android:label="Segments Service"/>

        <!-- OPTIONAL, if you want to receive push, push opened and registration completed intents -->
        <!-- Replace the receiver below with your package and class name -->
        <receiver android:name="com.younix.push.sample.IntentReceiver" />



    </application>

</manifest>
```

Logcat looks like this

```
12-06 11:27:51.052: D/Push Sample - UALib(848): Airship Take Off! Lib Version: 2.0.2 / App key = *******************
12-06 11:27:51.052: D/Push Sample - UALib(848): In Production? false
12-06 11:27:51.102: E/Push Sample - UALib(848): Required permission com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE is unknown to PackageManager.
12-06 11:27:51.702: D/Push Sample - UALib(848): Initializing Push.
12-06 11:27:51.712: D/Push Sample - UALib(848): Initializing Location.
12-06 11:27:51.902: D/Push Sample - UALib(848): Location or background location are not enabled - deferring service start until foreground event.
12-06 11:27:51.902: D/Push Sample - UALib(848): Initializing Analytics.
12-06 11:27:52.102: D/Push Sample APID(848): null
12-06 11:27:52.222: V/Push Sample - UALib(848): New session: e9889d8c-e8c8-40b6-a3af-75987c61c55a
12-06 11:27:52.322: V/Push Sample - UALib(848): com.urbanairship.analytics.AppForegroundEvent - {"data":{"time_zone":19800,"session_id":"e9889d8c-e8c8-40b6-a3af-75987c61c55a","notification_types":["sound","vibrate"],"daylight_savings":false,"carrier":"Android","lib_version":"2.0.2","connection_type":"cell","package_version":"1.0","os_version":"4.1.2","connection_subtype":"UMTS"},"type":"app_foreground","event_id":"2e12ccce-0c4b-40fd-9c44-e5dd8401b0a5","time":"1354773472"}
12-06 11:27:52.332: V/Push Sample - UALib(848): com.urbanairship.analytics.ActivityStartedEvent - {"data":{"class_name":"com.younix.push.sample.MainActivity","session_id":"e9889d8c-e8c8-40b6-a3af-75987c61c55a"},"type":"activity_started","event_id":"e8739e18-5d22-4064-b416-ce5002fcba1b","time":"1354773472"}
12-06 11:27:52.332: I/Push Sample - UALib(848): Service is not bound
12-06 11:27:52.382: D/Push Sample - UALib(848): Push Service started with intent=Intent { act=com.urbanairship.push.START cmp=com.younix.push.sample/com.urbanairship.push.PushService }
12-06 11:27:52.412: E/Push Sample - UALib(848): Push enabled: false
12-06 11:27:52.422: V/Push Sample - UALib(848): Push is disabled.  Not starting Push Service.
12-06 11:27:52.473: V/Push Sample - UALib(848): com.younix.push.sample.urbanairship.analytics.APP_FOREGROUND
12-06 11:27:52.662: D/dalvikvm(848): GC_CONCURRENT freed 223K, 4% free 8183K/8519K, paused 13ms+99ms, total 168ms
12-06 11:27:52.712: V/Push Sample - UALib(848): Push Service destroyed
12-06 11:27:52.782: D/gralloc_goldfish(848): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-06 11:27:53.542: V/Push Sample - UALib(848): EventService startService
12-06 11:27:53.842: V/Push Sample - UALib(848): EventService startService
12-06 11:28:52.103: V/Push Sample - UALib(848): Next upload time is in the past. Not scheduling a future upload.
12-06 11:28:52.442: D/Push Sample - UALib(848): Notifying of change to content://com.younix.push.sample.urbanairship.provider/preferences/com.urbanairship.analytics.LAST_SEND/insert
12-06 11:28:52.454: V/Push Sample - UALib(848): Notified of change of key com.urbanairship.analytics.LAST_SEND
12-06 11:28:52.522: I/Push Sample - UALib(848): Sending 2 events.
12-06 11:28:52.562: V/Push Sample - UALib(848): Set Timeout: 60000
12-06 11:28:52.562: V/Push Sample - UALib(848): Set Socket Buffer Size: 16384
12-06 11:28:52.572: V/Push Sample - UALib(848): GZIP'd: 592 into 352 (expected 148)
12-06 11:28:52.642: I/Push Sample - UALib(848): Sending Analytics to: https://combine.urbanairship.com/warp9/
12-06 11:28:56.252: I/Push Sample - UALib(848): Warp 9 response: 200
12-06 11:28:56.352: D/Push Sample - UALib(848): Notifying of change to content://com.younix.push.sample.urbanairship.provider/preferences/com.urbanairship.analytics.MAX_TOTAL_DB_SIZE/insert
12-06 11:28:56.362: V/Push Sample - UALib(848): Notified of change of key com.urbanairship.analytics.MAX_TOTAL_DB_SIZE
12-06 11:28:56.423: D/Push Sample - UALib(848): Notifying of change to content://com.younix.push.sample.urbanairship.provider/preferences/com.urbanairship.analytics.MAX_BATCH_SIZE/insert
12-06 11:28:56.432: V/Push Sample - UALib(848): Notified of change of key com.urbanairship.analytics.MAX_BATCH_SIZE
12-06 11:28:56.483: D/Push Sample - UALib(848): Notifying of change to content://com.younix.push.sample.urbanairship.provider/preferences/com.urbanairship.analytics.MAX_WAIT/insert
12-06 11:28:56.492: V/Push Sample - UALib(848): Notified of change of key com.urbanairship.analytics.MAX_WAIT
12-06 11:28:56.572: D/Push Sample - UALib(848): Notifying of change to content://com.younix.push.sample.urbanairship.provider/preferences/com.urbanairship.analytics.MIN_BATCH_INTERVAL/insert
```

Any hints about what's happening or what I forgot to add to my project?

Comment: are you try to implement new feature of C2DM or it is already implemented before 6 months ?? I am asking this because C2DM is depricated now

Comment: you mean, i can't integrate urban airshipsdk for android push notification, i just tried sample app given in urbanarship sdk by treating my own Package Id.

Comment: After checking document for urban airship sdk https://docs.urbanairship.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=819543 in the very first line they mention that you have to switch to [GCM Push](https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Getting+Started%3A+Android%3A+GCM+Push)

Comment: please check the manifest file in this Document https://docs.urbanairship.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1509252
urbaniarship still using C2DM permission to implement it in GCM

Comment: I'm seeing this also on Kindle Fire HD (Android 4.0.4)

Answer (score 5):

Hi I faced the same problem. The solution is pretty simple though. Just make a new emulator that supports Google APIs. It will be there in your virtual manager. That is the problem :)